# Matching specific table within HTML, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this problem. There're several similar tables on the page I'm trying to scrape.

```
<h2 class="tabellen_ueberschrift al">Points</h2>
<div class="fl" style="width:49%;">     
<table class="tabelle_grafik lh" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
```

The only difference between them is the text within `h2` tags, here: `Points`

How can I specifiy which table I need to search in?

I have this code and need to adjust the `h2` tag factor:

```
my_tab = soup.find('table', {'class':'tabelle_grafik lh'})
```

Need some help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.  Find the "previousSiblings" and if you find a h2 with the text "Points" before an h2 tag with a different text contents, you've found a good table

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

t="""
<h2 class="tabellen_ueberschrift al">Points</h2>
<table class="tabelle_grafik lh" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<th><td>yes me!</th></td></table>
<h2 class="tabellen_ueberschrift al">Bad</h2>
<table class="tabelle_grafik lh" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<th><td>woo woo</td></th></table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(t)

for ta in soup.findAll('table'):
    for s in ta.findPreviousSiblings():
        if s.name == u'h2':
            if s.text == u'Points':
                print ta 
            else:
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a job for [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). But, *BeautifulSoup doesn't support XPath expressions*.

Consider switching to [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

FYI, for test xml like:

```
<html>
<h2 class="tabellen_ueberschrift al">Points</h2>  
<div class="fl" style="width:49%;">   
<table class="tabelle_grafik lh" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">a</table>
</div>

<h2 class="tabellen_ueberschrift al">Illegal</h2>
<div class="fl" style="width:49%;">     
<table class="tabelle_grafik lh" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">b</table>
</div>
</html>
```

XPath expression to find table with class "tabelle_grafik lh" in div after h2="Points" is:

```
//table[@class="tabelle_grafik lh" and ../preceding-sibling::h2[1][text()="Points"]]
```

Comment: This can be accomplished with BeautifulSoup. You can iterate through the tables via `Siblings` and find the one you are looking for. Look at Vorsprung's answer.

Comment: @serk, yes, thanks. I just wanted to point out that `xpath` is a right tool for the job. So I think the answer can stay here as an alternative solution for the problem.