# pulling links and scraping those pages in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape some links from this page.

```
http://www.covers.com/pageLoader/pageLoader.aspx?page=/data/wnba/teams/pastresults/2012/team665231.html
```

This gets the links that I want.

```
boxurl = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(boxurl)
boxscores = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('boxscore'))
```

I would like to scrape every boxscore from the page.  I have already made the code to scrape the boxscore but I don't know how to get at them.

edit

I guess this way would be better since it strips out the html tags.  I still need to know how to open them.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('boxscore')):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

**edit2:**
This is how I scrape some of the data from the first link of the page.

```
url = 'http://www.covers.com/pageLoader/pageLoader.aspx?page=/data/wnba/results/2012/boxscore841602.html'


boxurl = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(boxurl)
def _unpack(row, kind='td'):
    return [val.text for val in row.findAll(kind)]

tables = soup('table')
linescore = tables[1]   
linescore_rows = linescore.findAll('tr')
roadteamQ1 = float(_unpack(linescore_rows[1])[1])
roadteamQ2 = float(_unpack(linescore_rows[1])[2])
roadteamQ3 = float(_unpack(linescore_rows[1])[3])
roadteamQ4 = float(_unpack(linescore_rows[1])[4]) 

print roadteamQ1, roadteamQ2, roadteamQ3, roadteamQ4
```

However when I try this.

```
url = 'http://www.covers.com/pageLoader/pageLoader.aspx?    page=/data/wnba/teams/pastresults/2012/team665231.html'
boxurl = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(boxurl)

tables = pages[0]('table')
linescore = tables[1]   
linescore_rows = linescore.findAll('tr')
roadteamQ1 = float(_unpack(linescore_rows[1])[1])
roadteamQ2 = float(_unpack(linescore_rows[1])[2])
roadteamQ3 = float(_unpack(linescore_rows[1])[3])
roadteamQ4 = float(_unpack(linescore_rows[1])[4])
```

I get this error.   **tables = pages0**  **TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

```
print pages[0]
```

spits out all of the html of the first link like normal.  Hopefully that's not too confusing.  To summarize I can get the links now but still can scrape from them.

Comment: If you're using that page as a "crawl" base - you may wish to look into [scrapy](http://scrapy.org)

Comment: now your question is clearer you might like to look at a previous answer I did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866297/matching-specific-table-within-html-beautifulsoup/15866957#15866957  All you have to do is work at it systematically, it's not difficult, just tedious!

Comment: I can normally find and scrape the table that I want.  In this case it is the second table on the webpage. So tables = soup('table')
linescore = tables[1] selects the table that I want.  Where I am having trouble is opening the webpage from the link and then selecting the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this pulls all the pages of the found links into an array, so the first page is pages[0], second pages[1] etc

```
boxscores = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('boxscore'))
basepath =  "http://www.covers.com"
pages=[]
for a in boxscores:
   pages.append(urllib2.urlopen(basepath + a['href']).read())
```

Comment: Yes, that works but I cant scrape from it.  I will explain the problem more in the original question.